# How to set text under the map mark like original google map mark

Tags: android-studio

[original google map mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77pEB.jpg)
I want to do this like[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77pEB.jpg)

the text under the mark or on top

but i can't find the perfect answer

now i can make a mark. The mark icon make by url.

use this way to make mark

```
private Bitmap writeTextOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text) {

        Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromURL(drawableId);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setLinearText(true);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));

        paint.setTextSize(35);

        Rect textRect = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);


        //Calculate the positions
//        int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - 2;     //-2 is for regulating the x position offset

        //"- ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)" is the distance from the baseline to the center.
//        int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)) ;

        canvas.drawText(text, canvas.getHeight() + 2, canvas.getHeight() + 2, paint);

        return  bm;
    }
```

but i dont like this way, becuz the text is panited in the icon.

like this
[painted in icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9za60.jpg)

how can i do perfect like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77pEB.jpg) that user clearly know what is this mark

Answer (score 0):

i find my perfect

i creat a new mark layout

have a imgview and a textview(under tge img view)

every mark creat by this layout

set the img and text

like this[finished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRNDD.jpg)

i reference from this url [url](http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/)